# How to query table with many to many relationship where count condition is met

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There are 3 models:

- Group (with function Broadcasts() defining hasMany to Broadcast)
- Broadcast (with function Groups() defining hasMany to Group)
- GroupBroadcast (with functions Broadcast() and Group() defining parents)

The goal is to find groups in which no more than 5 broadcasts in 24 hours is sent to.

Something like:

```
Group::whereDoesntHave("Broadcasts", function($q) {
    $q->where("Count sent broadcasts in 24", "<=", 5);
})->get();
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eloquent's whereHas method which receives the relationship, a callback, an operator and a count.

Try this:

```php
$groups = Group::whereHas('broadcasts', function ($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subDay(), today()]);
}, '<=', 5)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition in `has()`.  Try this:

```
Group::whereHas('broadcasts', function ($query) {
  $query->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subDays(1), today()]);
})->has('broadcasts','>', 5)->get();
```